# SpraedPdf -images not displayed with https

Tags: symfony, pdf, twig

I am using the symfony-framework with the SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle to generate PDFs. It works perfectly until I use it on a server which uses https.
I am using a twig-template and render it with the pdfGenerator:

```
$html = $this->renderView("documents/pdf/document.html.twig", array([..]));
$pdfGenerator = $this->get('spraed.pdf.generator');
$pdf = $pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html);
```

Images were copied to an tmp-directory and the template loads it with an absolute path:

```
<img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset(logo) }}" height="100" />
```

It works until I use a server with https. The image is not displayed on the pdf (but if I output the html, the image is shown).

If I exclude the tmp-dir (where the image is stored) from the https-redirect (in the apache-site-config):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!tmp).*)$ https://mypage.com/$1
```

and change the path of the image to http://:

```
<img src="{{ 'http://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset(logo) }}" height="100" />
```

it works.

So I think the problem is that the pdfgenerator cannot load images from https.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

edit:

Short form:
If the image-source starts with http, the image can be loaded. If the image-source starts with https, the image can't be loaded. If I echo the html of the pdf, the image is shown, so the absolute-URI is correct.

Comment: You can't load non-https content on a https domain, meaning you need to link the image  as https as well

Comment: you understood me wrong. I can only load the image if I "force" it to http (exclude the tmp-dir from the https-redirect). If I use https, it doesn't work. If disable the https redirect (use http for the entire page), it also works

Comment: I'm sorry. Misread that part yes. Then it will be a bug of the library. I can't see into the source as it seems this lib uses `java`?